# phpMyAdmin with RDS & Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I have an app loaded with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and DB at Amazon RDS. My Application is able to contact Database which is functioning well and I can connect to mySQL from AWS EC2 CLI.

Problem:    I can't get phpMyAdmin to connect to my Amazon RDS instance.
            (Error #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server)

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
       Require ip ::1

     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

`/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`

```
$i = 0;


$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'MYAWSRDS.rds.amazonaws.com'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'username'  // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          // If set to a db-name, only
                                                    // this db is displayed in left frame
                                                    // It may also be an array of db-names, where sorting order is relevant.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']       = '';          // Database name to be hidden from listings
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';          // Database used for Relation, Bookmark and PDF Features
                                                    // (see scripts/create_tables.sql)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'phpmyadmin'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = '';          // Bookmark table
                                                    //   - leave blank for no bookmark support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_bookmark'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']      = '';          // table to describe the relation between links (see doc)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no relation-links support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_relation'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']    = '';          // table to describe the display fields
                                                    //   - leave blank for no display fields support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']  = '';          // table to describe the tables position for the PDF schema
                                                    //   - leave blank for no PDF schema support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_coords'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']     = '';          // table to describe pages of relationpdf
                                                    //   - leave blank if you don't want to use this
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_pdf_pages'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']   = '';          // table to store column information
                                                    //   - leave blank for no column comments/mime types
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_column_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']       = '';          // table to store SQL history
                                                    //   - leave blank for no SQL query history
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_history'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose_check'] = TRUE;        // set to FALSE if you know that your pma_* tables
                                                    // are up to date. This prevents compatibility
                                                    // checks and thereby increases performance.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // whether to allow root login
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order']           // Host authentication order, leave blank to not use
                                     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']           // Host authentication rules, leave blank for defaults
                                     = array();
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']              // Allow logins without a password. Do not change the FALSE
                                     = FALSE;       // default unless you're running a passwordless MySQL server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']              // Leave blank (default) for no Designer support, otherwise
                                     = '';          // set to suggested 'pma_designer_coords' if really needed
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 50;          //   DEFAULT: '50'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold']      // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 600;         //   DEFAULT: '600'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold']        // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'


$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir']   = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/save';


$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: What server is phpMyAdmin running on? The same AWS EC2 server where you connected from the command line client?

Comment: yeah, phpMyAdmin is on same EC2 server

Answer (score 0):

In `config.inc.php` try using `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';` or `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`

What is probably happening is that your MySQL server is not accepting connections from outside IP addresses; when you use the full hostname in the host directive it appears to come from an external connection (even though it's on the same machine the networking looks up the host differently). Either of those values will force it to connect without going to the external address (though they use different means which is why we'll try both).

When trying with 'localhost' you may also need to change the connect_type to 'socket'.

Comment: MySQL server is a different one not EC2, its RDS - so I have to use extenal IP only

Comment: Did you try using the internal IP of the RDS instance? Not the RDS endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This was taken from a comment in another similar question:

Try changing the host to your RDS endpoint:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost' to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

Comment: Its the same piece of code I have and its not working. Anyways thank you for your effort.

Comment: I was having a similar problem, but ended up using mysql workbench on my development computer instead of phpmyadmin. It took 5 mins to set up. But for phomyadmin someone recommended using the internal IP of the RDS instance instead of the external domain endpoint as it's calling from within aws itself. Didn't end up trying it though my self. Hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: I sorted it by setting up adminer instead of phpMyAdmin, though I just wanna know what has been the problem